# Phonegap/Cordova Facebook plugin rejected by Facebook

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, facebook-login

Facebook rejects the implementation of the [official Phonegap Facebook plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

Did it by the book, login, posting works. Explained it's Phonegap (v3.0), and it's using their native SDK, but got rejected two times without any explanation except the info below.

```
Your Android app must use the native Login dialog that comes with Facebook's SDKs instead of custom web views. Ensure you have successfully tested your Facebook Login integration for Single Sign On or remove this integration as a listed platform in the developer app.
```

Here are the [full details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoSh3.jpg)

Please advise. Thx!

Comment: Well according to the page that you linked to on the github issue, you need to use the facebook android SDK to do the login. Cordova uses a custom web view to display your html5 content. When you ask users to login, apparently the plugin is asking users to log in again, instead of just using the credentials stored on the phone. The plugin says it has the facebook sdk but apparently it's not using the login functionality.

Comment: That's what's bothering me, it works like it should. It inovokes the facebook api me.facebook.authorize(cordova.getActivity(), me.permissions, new AuthorizeListener(me)); not some webview. After that is executed your native facebook application pops up and requests permission, or if you've already authorized it doesn't even show up. If facebook is not installed it shows a webview but Facebook sdk does that itself.....

Comment: Maybe whoever at facebook reviewed your app just freaked out when they saw that there is a custom webview (the cordova container) and didn't dig deep enough to see that the plugin actually uses the native Facebook Android SDK. Have you seen anyone else having problems with this? It says their rules changed Oct 2...are you just the first person to submit since then?
Is there any way to dispute or contact Facebook? Maybe try submitting it again and see if you get a different reviewer?  Sorry I don't really have any other advice :/

Comment: Good thinking, since the current versions of the app that is on the store does not have the Facebook integration, so they couldn't test it. I'll try to write a thorough explanation with screenshots and see if it helps. Thx for your comments.

Comment: Explained it to them, added screenshots where they can see that native login is used, they just rejected it without any additional explanation...

Comment: Ugh...I'd suggest going to the plugin maintainer and asking but it looks like that plugin is either abondoned or there is no owner or something. It says "Official Cordova Facebook Plugin" but I have no idea who made it "official". Apache probably shouldn't be supporting this and I doubt Facebook is participating. I did see that Adobe has one in their PGB plugins: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/257 and https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect  Again not sure if they are supported but you could start looking around there. See if the code is different, if any other ppl have problems.

Comment: Also I'd suggest emailing the adobe email address on that PGB page asking what's going on. I'll try to figure out what's going on with the plugin you are using, eg, who is supporting it and whats going on with it.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: Nope, no answer from FB except the automated rejection and no answer from Adobe plugin maintainer.